# How do I start the "Put a Record On" mission in Control?

Tags: control

I found a coin and talked to Arish, and I've selected "Put a Record On" from my missions list.  I found the jukebox, but when I press the button, I get the Expeditions menu.  I tried going on an expedition, but that's not what the walkthroughs describe.

Is there some trick to completing the mission, or is the game just broken?

Apparently, [I'm not the only one with this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/controlgame/comments/k3ua4c/please_help_with_the_put_a_record_on_mission/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).  Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, mine had the same issue. The mission just kept open, until I eventually finished (completed) the 1st tier of the expedition. I could then go back and talk with Arish and finish the mission.